# Customizing the Infopath 2010 Error?

Tags: infopath

I want to customize the error message that infopath gives if a field is blank. I have a Submit & Save button and on its click if any field is blank, it should show a popup that  'Fields with * are mandatory'.

currently infopath gives it default error msg ...which is too complex for a user to read and understand.

How do i customize this msg on the button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that message is configurable. The common approach is to have a standard button for the Submit, which uses rules to validate the fields and then unhides a section with an error message. The last step on that button is the save, but if any of the validation rules find errors, that last step will not be executed.

Also see my answer here: [Cannot be blank as rule in sharepoint designer and infopath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80183/cannot-be-blank-as-rule-in-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath/80197#80197)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to convert the standard button as Submit button and how to associate the rules.

Comment: Use a normal button and create rules. `Submit using a data connection` is one of the actions that can be defined. `Close this form` is another one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add your data validation and specify the ScreenTip and Message.

1. Got to field's Properties -> Data Validation
2. Click Add
3. Define the condition, 'If Field is blank then...'
4. Specify ScreenTip and Message

That message will be displayed per field and not exactly how you want it, to show in one place for all required fields.